# Rails Error: undefined method `private_method_defined?' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create and save an object, but I keep getting the error:

```
undefined method `private_method_defined?' for nil:NilClass
```

I wrote some simple code to work out the bug.
In the controller, the code looks like this:

```
def testtutor
     @t = Tutor.new
     @t.fname = 'Test'
end
```

The model is mostly blank:

```
class Tutor < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :branch
end
```

The error occurs at:

```
@t.fname = 'Test'
```

Any idea what could be going on? I have created and migrated a "tutors" table, and "fname" is one of the fields.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs if any database column names conflict with rails.

I faced the same issue when I had a column called "class".

Renaming it will fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go into the console and try creating an entry there. 
`t = Tutor.new`

Then type

`t.valid?`

If it says false type

`t.errors.full_messages` and it will print out exactly what the issues are

Hope that helps